# how to make class to not allow creating new object (new Object())

Tags: java, new-operator

I am developing a library and I don't want the user to create an instance of a class directly with the `new` keyword, instead I have special methods to create objects. So is it possible if the user instantiates a class using the `new` keyword, that the compiler gives error.
For Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass(int i) {  }

    public MyClass createMyClassInt(int i) {
        return new MyClass(i);
    }

    private MyClass(double d) { }

    public MyClass createMyClassDouble(double d) {
        return new MyClass(d);
    }
}
```

So when the user tries to instantiate `MyClass myClass = new MyClass();`, the compiler will give an error.

Comment: have you tried the code?

Comment: That's what it does now.  Can you say how this code doesn't do what you want already? (You could format it more nicely ;)

Comment: @Rp-: not necessary if there are already other (private) constructors.

Comment: @l46kok: Thx.. I didnt knew this concept..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is *nearly* fine - all you need is to make your `create` methods static, and give them a return type:

```
public static MyClass createMyClassInt(int i) {
  return new MyClass(i);
}

public static MyClass createMyClassDouble(double d) {
  return new MyClass(d);
}
```

The methods have to be static so that the caller doesn't *already* have to have a reference to an instance in order to create a new instance :)

EDIT: As noted in comments, it's probably also worth making the class `final`.

Comment: Can you tell me if singleton is used then will it be fine?

Comment: @nick: It doesn't *look* like this is a suitable candidate for the singleton pattern, no... the caller might want to create multiple instances with different values. (Personally I dislike the singleton pattern in general, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok Sir. SO apart from Singleton, what you suggest me to prefer,if i want just a single object.

Comment: @nick: It sounds like your comments are off-topic for this question - I suggest you ask a separate question, with a lot more context.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to create your class by special method why dont use factory design pattern?
static method inside your class which returns you new instance of class

if you just dont want to create new class by default constructor, and you want to force user to use one with parameter, then just don't implement default constructor